# Can you create variables consisting of header values too be summed up via pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, report

I have a dataframe consisting of 400 columns with individual headers. Each header is a swap derivative futures contract with the volume of each day in each row.

I was wondering if it is possible to make different lists/grouping of the contracts' names saved as a variable to then have a function execute the sum of volume of each grouping per day. I can then later edit the grouping name in the future. Some of these groupings to be summed each day can have up to 90 different contracts. I have created an Excel file to list the names of the contracts for Front Month Volume, Back Month Volume, Total Volume All Contracts, Etc

For example,

Grouping 1: Front Month Open Interest would consist of ['March 2022 Contract'],['Sep 2021 Contract'], ['Dec Contract 2021'] to be summed up for each day.

Grouping 2: Back Months Open Interest would be ['June 2021 Contract'],['March 2021 Contract'], etc. to be summed up each day. Every day this .csv adds a row with the values for each of the 400 contracts.

Any direction would greatly appreciated. I have been trying to find an example of creating variable of header values that I can change on the side which are then later summed.

EDIT*
[Here is a picture of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGUC5.png)

I am looking to create a variable outside of the program I can reference that contains a list of different groupings. For example here is a snippet of a spreadsheet. I would like these groupings to be a variable or list that I can edit as it changes quarterly.

[Snippet of Groupings example, only did a few contracts, but will be long list of 30+ contracts to be summed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmyyk.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to guess at what your dataframe looks like, so if you could post a scaled down version if the example below is incorrect, that would be helpful.

Anywho, if your df is just dates, volumes, and headers, this example takes the header groupings and slices the dataframe based on column names and sums the volumes by day. From here you can figure out how to write that to excel or adapt the code as needed

```
df = pd.DataFrame([range(1,9),range(11,19),range(21,29),range(31,39),range(41,49),range(51,59),range(61,69)], 
                columns=['Contract 1','Contract 2','Contract 3','Contract 4','Contract 5','Contract 6','Contract 7','Contract 8'],
                index=pd.date_range(start='10/1/2021', periods=7))

group1 = ['Contract 1', 'Contract 2', 'Contract 3']
group2 = ['Contract 3', 'Contract 4', 'Contract 5','Contract 7', 'Contract 8']
group3 = ['Contract 1', 'Contract 8']

groups=[group1, group2, group3]

for g in groups:
    print(df[g])
    print(df[g].sum(axis=1))
```

Output

```
            Contract 1  Contract 2  Contract 3
2021-10-01           1           2           3
2021-10-02          11          12          13
2021-10-03          21          22          23
2021-10-04          31          32          33
2021-10-05          41          42          43
2021-10-06          51          52          53
2021-10-07          61          62          63
2021-10-01      6
2021-10-02     36
2021-10-03     66
2021-10-04     96
2021-10-05    126
2021-10-06    156
2021-10-07    186
Freq: D, dtype: int64
            Contract 3  Contract 4  Contract 5  Contract 7  Contract 8
2021-10-01           3           4           5           7           8
2021-10-02          13          14          15          17          18
2021-10-03          23          24          25          27          28
2021-10-04          33          34          35          37          38
2021-10-05          43          44          45          47          48
2021-10-06          53          54          55          57          58
2021-10-07          63          64          65          67          68
2021-10-01     27
2021-10-02     77
2021-10-03    127
2021-10-04    177
2021-10-05    227
2021-10-06    277
2021-10-07    327
Freq: D, dtype: int64
            Contract 1  Contract 8
2021-10-01           1           8
2021-10-02          11          18
2021-10-03          21          28
2021-10-04          31          38
2021-10-05          41          48
2021-10-06          51          58
2021-10-07          61          68
2021-10-01      9
2021-10-02     29
2021-10-03     49
2021-10-04     69
2021-10-05     89
2021-10-06    109
2021-10-07    129
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I edited my question to include where I am at on the dataframe and the Excel spreadsheet of the contracts to be grouped.

Your example: group1 = ['Contract 1', 'Contract 2', 'Contract 3'] is exactly what I am looking to create but have group1 be a variable outside the program I can edit. I guess it might be a better question to ask is how do I format these contract names into your example. 

Thanks